# Mongodb schema approachs

Tags: mongodb, model, schema

I have mongodb database. I am not sure about my approach of creating models. For example, I have user, comic collection. Now I am adding 'add to list' feature like add to reading, dropped and etc. Is it good to create new collection with list name . Inside it there are comicId, userId ,listType, last chapter fields. And when I need this data in service I will use aggregate function to get all needed data. Is this good or there is more efficient way to do it? Thanks for answering!